# call sql procedure with parameters from python got "NoneType" object is not iterable error?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I want to call a sql procedure from Python to insert log into a sql table. However, I'm getting the following error. Can someone help? Thanks.

> "'NoneType' object is not iterable".

Python code to call above procedure:

```
procedure='exec dbo.p_update_prod_log @project=?, @step=?, @msg_number=?, @msg_text=?, @msg_date=?, @prod_status_id=?'
parameters=('1', '2', '3', '4', '2016-06-22', '6')
# tried parameters=['1', '2', '3', '4', '2016-06-22', '6'] with no luck

pd.read_sql(sql=procedure, con=self.conn, params=parameters)
```

The sql procedure:

```sql
ALTER procedure [dbo].[p_update_prod_log] (
        @project nvarchar(255)
        , @step nvarchar(255)=null
        , @msg_number int=null
        , @msg_text nvarchar(255)=null
        , @msg_date datetime=null
        , @prod_status_id int=null)
as begin
    insert into prod_log (createdon, createdbyproject, createdbyprojectstep, message_number, message_text, message_date, prod_status_id)
    select GETDATE()
        , @project
        , @step
        , @msg_number
        , @msg_text
        , @msg_date
        , @prod_status_id
end
```

Trace:

```
  File "Z:/../code\sql_linker.py", line 54, in call_procedure
    df = pd.read_sql(sql=procedure, con=self.conn, params=parameters)                
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 399, in read_sql
    chunksize=chunksize)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1437, in read_query
    columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cursor.description]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Your parameters should be a list. Try using brackets []

Comment: Tried with no luck@Jon Ekiz , same error

Comment: Documentation says :

"params : list, tuple or dict, optional, default: None
List of parameters to pass to execute method. The syntax used to pass parameters is database driver dependent. Check your database driver documentation for which of the five syntax styles, described in PEP 249’s paramstyle, is supported. Eg. for psycopg2, uses %(name)s so use params={‘name’ : ‘value’}"

So maybe it's a dict ?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full traceback, not just the "'NoneType' object is not iterable" line.

Comment: @LukeWoodward added.Thx

Comment: Your stored procedure returns no resultset. It is only an action append query.

Comment: @Parfait correct the stored procedure returns nothing. It logs messages into sql. How can I make this work?

Comment: What do you want to do: append data or return results? Pandas is a data analysis library where `read_sql` is to extract data from RDBMS. Use your db connection cursor for action queries.